# How can I fix "cannot find declaration to go to" in WebStorm?

Tags: javascript, webstorm

I'm using WebStorm with JavaScript and when I press <kbd>F3</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl + Click</kbd> on function I get message that say "cannot find declaration to go to". This happens only in functions that I wrote on my computer, with other functions it works great.

I wrote my functions declarations exactly like all the other functions that go to declaration works for them.
I'm using Ultimate version.

I tried `File->Invalidate cache\Restart...` and it didn't work.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:
Example of the function:

```
    FaasInitUtils.prototype.createCompnentData = function createCompnentData(app) {

}
```

when I call this function I do it like this:

```
        FaasInitUtils.prototype.configureSiteCdmRT = function configureSiteCdmRT() {
var componentData = this.createCompnentData(app);
}
```

Comment: please attach to the issue a code sample

Comment: works fine for me when using similar code. Please can you provide a sample project that shows up the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I manged to fix it. I had a lot of projects and big one in Webstorm, what I excluded target folders and then everything started to work (including colors).
So I think that there is a problem with the configuration of memory limitation/consumption.

Comment: Yep, just right click the folder and remove the exclusion. Webstorm should reindex and you're back in business.

Answer (score 3):

Long shot: I had the same problem. For some reason in Preferences -> File Types -> JavaScript : there wasn't any pattern matching *.js files.
I added *.js and then it worked.
Cheers

Answer (score 2):

My case:

- go to WebStorm Default IDE directories (C:\Users\JohnS\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains)
- delete all files in this folder
- reopen WebStorm

**WARNING:** 
But after these steps your JetBrains products configuration will be reset.
So u can try to delete this folder WebStorm2020.1 (the name depends on WebStorm version) first and try is this will solve the problem, if not do my steps.

These steps fix for me this bug.
This article helps me to find Default IDE directories for my OS:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/tuning-the-ide.html#default-dirs

Comment: Thx! Deleting Webstorm2020.2 folder in C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\JetBrains did help

Answer (score 1):

1. Right-click on the closest `src/` folder from the file you want to navigate from.
2. Select `Mark Directory as`
3. Select `Sources Root`

This problem happens if for example you have a repo where you have a frontend folder and inside you have multiple apps where each one has a `src/` folder.
Then PyCharm/WebStorm takes your root folder (or maybe the first `src/` folder cascading from the root folder) as the root path for your imports relative paths.
Which is not the good root path for your frontend app imports because of the nesting.
So when you try to navigate to a function declaration, PyCharm/WebStorm cannot find the location starting from the root folder (and not your frontend app folder)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by deleting .idea folder from project